# How to combine multiple columns values into one column value?

Tags: sql-server

I have few columns which has values either 1 or 0. Final result i have to store in one column(F),
Which should perform OR operation.

[image]

Comment: Final result of what operation?

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin Coulmn F should have 1 when there is 1 in any one of the columns(a1,a2,a3)--OR operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when a1 + a2 + a3 > 0 then 1
       else 0 end as F from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

These are known as bitwise operators & described in the MS documentation.
By the sound of it the one you want is a pipe |

```
create table #t (cola bit,colb bit, colc bit) 

insert #t values(1,0,1)
insert #t values(1,1,0)
insert #t values(0,0,0)

select cola|colb|colc from #t
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15